# Get the latest modified C file

Tags: shell, unix, find, last-modified

How to use the Unix command to get the  file list in a directory tree (multiple directory in recursive manner) which are sorted by the modified time?

Comment: What did you try? Did you read some [find tutorial](http://content.hccfl.edu/faculty/wayne_pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm) or the [findutils documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) ?? You really should!!

Answer (score 1):

With `bash` 4 or `zsh` you could try

```
  ls -lt **/*.c
```

<sup>the above command works well if you have not too much such files. Otherwise you could reach the `ARG_MAX` limit of the kernel.</sup>

In particular, to list the latest `.c` file you could

```
  ls -lt **/*.c | head -1
```

With other shells, or if you have a lot of such files, e.g. more than several thousands -because of `ARG_MAX` kernel limit for [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) ...- you'll need to use `find`. As I commented, read the [findutils documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) and some [find tutorial](http://content.hccfl.edu/faculty/wayne_pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm).